# jQuery Mobile select menu not closing with HTML5 video

Tags: jquery, ipad, video, jquery-mobile

http://sandbox.solutionsbydesign.com/montage/ipad/

On the iPad for some reason the select dialog box wont disappear. Previous to inserting the video I had no issue with the select dialog box but after inserting HTML5 video the dialog box didn't want to close after opening. Is this a bug with jQuery mobile or with HTML5 video embedding?

Comment: Playing around some more I noticed that the video controls seems to still be accessible even with the dialog box. It seems as the the native video controls overlay the dialog box, not visibly tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a conflict with the native Quicktime player and the z-indexed elements. A workaround that I employed was to replace the native controls from Quicktime with my own control set using Javascript.